# Hibernate criteria query multiple criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

In my current project I've faced a problem of getting entities with hibernate criteria query. I have the following entities:

- Professor, which contains a list of students
- Student, which contains a list of assignments.
- Assignment, which contains id of student to which it is assigned to.

Now, I want to get all assignments relative to the professor, i.e. all assignments Professor assigned to his students.

This query shows what I want to implement in criteria query.

```
select * from Assigment p, Student a, Professor c where p.studentid = a.id and a.proffid = c.id and c.id = 2411;
```

How can I implement this query using hibernate criteria API?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

suppose your tables like that:

```
@Entity
public class Professor{
    K id;
    List<Student> students;
}

@Entity
public class Student{
    K profid;
    List<Assignments> assignments;
}

@Entity
public class Assignments{
    K studentid;
}
```

simple sample by using alias:

```
Criteria criteria = currentSession.createCriteria(Professor.class, "professor");
    criteria.createAlias("professor.students", "student");
    criteria.createAlias("student.assigments", "assigment");
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("professor.id", "student.profid"));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("assigment.studentid", "student.profid"));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", 2411));
return criteria.list();
```

Comment: what if I wanted to add a `Restriction.eq` for `professor.id` equals 1234, i.e. comparing a property directly to a `Long`?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Restrictions.eq("professor.id", 1234L)

Comment: Was looking for something like this! Glad this solution still works after 3 years :D

Comment: createCriteria is deprecated. Update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin + Spring Data JPA.
If entities have no relations in your code (@OneToMany, @ManyToOne, @ManyToMany, @OneToOne):

```
@Entity
data class Professor(
    @Id
    var id: Long?,
)

@Entity
data class Student(
    @Id
    var id: Long?,
    var professorId: Long,
)

@Entity
data class Assignment(
    @Id
    var id: Long?,
    var studentId: Long,
)

data class ResultModel(
    val professorId: Long,
    val studentId: Long,
    val assignmentId: Long,
)
```

The query might be like this:

```
val cb = entityManager.criteriaBuilder
val query = cb.createQuery(KfoProjectBySearchEntity::class.java)
val professor = query.from(Professor::class.java)
val student = query.from(Student::class.java)
val assignment = query.from(Assignment::class.java)
             
query.select(
    cb.construct(
        ResultModel::class.java,
        professor.get<Long>(Professor::id.name),
        student.get<Long>(Student::id.name),
        assignment.get<Long>(Assignment::id.name),
    )
).where(
    cb.and(
        cb.equal(
            professor.get<Long>(Professor::id.name),
            student.get<Long>(Student::professorId.name),
        ),
        cb.equal(
            student.get<Long>(Student::id.name),
            assignment.get<Long>(Assignment::studentId.name),
        ),
        cb.equal(
            professor.get<Long>(Professor::id.name),
            2411L,
        ),
        
    )
)
```