# Comparing a Collection's Field - org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:

Tags: java, hibernate

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13909409/409976) clearly describes how to set a `Restriction` to compare where 2 properties are equal.

Given these 2 entities in that answer:

```
@Entity
public class Professor{
    K id;
    List<Student> students;
}

@Entity
public class Student{
    K profid;
    String name;
}
```

How would I write the following `Restriction`: `where professor.students.name is "Kevin"`?

I tried something like:

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(Professor.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("students.name", "Kevin")
```

but that failed with:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: 
     'students.name' of: Professor
```

Comment: You need to add an alias first, like this `criteria.addAlias("students", "s");` and later you can use `Restrinctions.eq("s.name" "Kevin");`. The Alias is needed because the Criteria API don't join automatically

Comment: thanks, that worked. Care to post for credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a alias to the collection first, like this

```
Criteria criteria = createCriteria(Professor.class);
criteria.addAlias("students", "s");
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("s.name", "Kevin")
```

The Alias is needed because the Criteria API don't join automatically